# Having T type how to find all classes that expand Base<T> in assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, .net-assembly

Say I have:

```
public class Base<T> {}
public class MyBaseOne : Base<int> {}
public class MyBaseTwo : Base<int> {}
```

Having T type (say int) how to find all classes that expand Base in the assembly and be able to construct new objects of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Type.IsAssignableFrom`:

```
var typeArgument = typeof(int);
var baseType = typeof(Base<>).MakeGenericType(typeArgument);
var matches = someAssembly.GetTypes()
                          .Where(t => typeof(baseType).IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

That will work for the examples you've shown, but won't find (say) `Child<T>` where `Child` is described as:

```
public class Child<T> : Base<T>
```

I'm assuming you *do* want to find classes that are assignable to `Base<T>` but don't have `Base<T>` as the direct superclass (i.e. a longer type hierarchy). If you don't, it's even easier:

```
var matches = someAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == baseType);
```